# remove css class after x seconds on popup close

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a delete popup which works fine, but have added z-index on that, due to that it gets flickering effect. below is working code

```
<div className={modalOpen ? 'fullw content-holder has-scroll model-opened setHeaderZindex' : 'fullw content-holder has-scroll'}>
```

i want something like:

`<div className={modalOpen ? 'fullw content-holder has-scroll model-opened setHeaderZindex :
    otherState ? fullw content-holder has-scroll model-opened(which remove z-index class on setTimeout) : 'fullw content-holder has-scroll'(default class)} </div>`

I am trying to remove 'setHeaderZindex' using setTimeout.
sample video link
[demo video](https://a.uguu.se/kmmSXfGRYu0o.mov)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `useState` hook after `setTimeout`

```
  export default function App() {
    const [className, setClassName] = useState('fullw content-holder has-scroll model-opened')
    setTimeout(() => {
      setClassName('fullw content-holder has-scroll model-opened setHeaderZindex');
    }, 2000)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <h1 className={className}>World</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve problem with styled-components. The simple example of how it works.

```
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  ${props => props.something ? 'display: flex;' : 'display: none;'}
`

return <StyledDiv something={modalOpen} />
```

Comment: application doesn't use styled components. so wont be useful that much.